# Finding closest date in a datetime list

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I have been using this code to find the closest date in a list that is before the input date. However I found a bug recently that crashes the code when the input date is the same as the first date in the list.

allDates is a list of dates eg. 1/1/2015, 5/1/2015, 10/1/2015

inputDate is the date that the user selects

```
var closestDate = allDates.Where(x => x < inputDate).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

When I tried selecting the first date in the list eg, 1/1/2015 the closest date comes out empty

Also right now if I select a date in the list, eg if the list contains 5/1/2015 and i select 5/1/2015, it does not select 5/1/2015 but select the earlier date in the list, right now I did a dirty workaround by reducing all the date in the list's date by 1

Comment: Is `allDates` a query to a SQL table?  Is `inputDate` a `DateTime`.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that suggests SQL is being used at all, never mind makes clear _how_ it's being used here (source of `allDates`? destination of the result?). If you are writing the default value of `DateTime` to a SQL database, that's probably not going to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on posting a question that is useful. Please edit your question so that it provides enough information for someone to provide a _good_ answer. Make sure to include the exact error information including full stack trace.

Comment: Correction , I meant the closest date is empty. The error code comes from when I wanted to insert into db

Comment: Can you let me know if `5/1/2015` represents the 5th of Jan or the 1st of May?

Comment: its in the dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the second issue use `<=` instead of `<a`.

```
var closestDate = allDates
  .Where(x => x <= inputDate)
  .DefaultIfEmpty()
  .Max();
```

Could the first issue be an invalid `inputDate`?